# PopupMenuButton page redirect on select

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a popup bar that is created at the moment. I want to redirect it to other pages based on the selection. I am having trouble to manage `onSelected`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Choice _selectedChoice = choices[0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = "AppBar demo";
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(choices[0].icon),
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[0]);
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(choices[1].icon),
              onPressed: () {
                _select(choices[1]);
              },
            ),
            PopupMenuButton<Choice>(
              onSelected: _select,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return choices.skip(2).map((Choice choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<Choice>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice.title)
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: ChoiceCard(choice: _selectedChoice),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _select(Choice choice) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedChoice = choice;
    });
  }
}

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Choice choice;

  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                choice.icon,
                size: 128.0,
              ),
              Text(choice.title, style: textStyle)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway),
  const Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk),
];
```

Where do I need to define other pages/widget/class details? Also how onselected works in this case?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpjfR5rG2lM) link.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this link. It helped me a lot and it clears all the doubts. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

every Time a `PopUpMenuItem` is selected, the `onSelected:` void function `_select` calls with the parameter `value: choice`

with the `setState()`, the `Statefull` Class _MyAppState updates with the new value `_selectedChoice`

if you want to parse new Pages, you can define a `widget` in the `ChoiceCard()`
that is a new Class you can place it in any new dart file...

```
class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon, this.widget});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final Widget widget;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Car', icon: Icons.directions_car, widget: Page1()),
  const Choice(title: 'Bicycle', icon: Icons.directions_bike, widget: Page2()),
  const Choice(title: 'Boat', icon: Icons.directions_boat, widget: Page3()),
  const Choice(title: 'Bus', icon: Icons.directions_bus, widget: Page4()),
  const Choice(title: 'Train', icon: Icons.directions_railway, widget: Page5()),
  const Choice(title: 'Walk', icon: Icons.directions_walk, widget: Page6()),
];

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(new Text("Page1"));
  }
}
```

Call the Widget in the Scaffold:

```
body: _selectedChoice.widget,
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will go through it. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix it by using below code.

```
void _select(Choice choice) {
    if(choice.title == 'Bus'){
      print('Bus');
    }else if(choice.title == 'Car'){
      print('Car');
    }
  }
```

Basically we need to use choice.title and then based on the condition it is printing the values.

Now I am working on page redirect using the same code by removing Print with Function.
That is not working at the moment.